# LinearSolve on non-square matrices?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I just came across a strange behaviour for LinearSolve (on Mathematica 8.0.0.0). Consider the following definitions:

```
foo = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
bar = {0, 0, 1};
```

Then `LinearSolve[foo, bar]` gives the expected `{1,0}`. The same is true for `LinearSolve[SparseArray@foo, bar]`. Moreover, `LinearSolve[N@foo, bar]` gives a numeric approximation of that vector, as expected.

However `LinearSolve[N@SparseArray@foo, bar]` does not work, but gives me an error message

> LinearSolve::sqmat: The matrix SparseArray[Automatic,{3,2},0.,{1,{{0,0,1,3},{{2},{1},{2}}},{1.,1.,1.}}] is not square. A square matrix is needed to compute a factorization. >>

Unfortunately my actual problem is exactly of the latter case: A non-square numeric sparse matrix.

Now my question is: Why do I get that error, and more importantly, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearSolve[(N@SparseArray)@foo, bar]
```

Comment: That applies `N` only to the symbol `SparseArray` and thus is equivalent to `SparseArray@foo`. You can easily verify that by noting that the result consists of integers, not of m,achine-precision numbers. Note that the point is not the application of N, but the fact that I have a sparse array with numeric values; Applying `N` is just a convenient way to get that.